# Adding field on findOne in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to add a field on findOne operation which will contain a size of an inner array of the document
Example:

```
{ "_id": "1"
"children": [1,2,3]
}
```

I want to get a new field name "numOfChildren": 3 after the findOne operation.
Is this possible?

Update:
I cannot do it as @chridam suggested, as I need to slice the array
The whole query:

```
$children = $this->_childrenCollection->findOne(
                    array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),
                    array('children' => array('$slice' => 100))
                );
```

Comment: Do you want to get the whole number (not $sliced) of elements? Or the number of elements returned by your query? Per example, if you have 200 elements, what do you expect to get in your new field? 200 or 100?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay Yep, I want to get 200 - the total number of the array members.

Comment: Ok, so may I ask why do you $slice you're array? Are you afraid to have too many results?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay yes, i can have an array of thousands, so I want to slice it. But still get the original array size within one simple Mongo query.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the [**aggregation framework**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/), in particular the [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline operator which uses the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator to calculate the size of the array, project that result to the new field.

To get a single result similar to the `findOne()` method, use the **[`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)** method to the cursor returned from the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$project" : {          
            "children": 1,
            "numOfChildren": {
                "$size": "$children"
            }
       }
    }
];

var resultArray = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();

if (resultArray.length > 0) { printjson (resultArray[0]); }
```

PHP example implementation:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");
$c = $m->selectDB("test")->selectCollection("collectionName");
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "children" => 1,
            "numOfChildren"   => array(             
                "$size" => "$children"
            )
        )
    )
);
$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. I do use the aggregation framework for this, but I don't always need to (At least I thought so), so in order to save aggregation operations, I tried to use single findOne operation. I do not have the entire array size on return because I'm making array('children' => array('$slice' => 100)) as I only want the first 100. I've updated the whole query